# How can I check one table for an entry but use default value if it doesn't exist?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, join

I have 2 tables. `TableA` has columns **OldLogin** and **NewLogin**. `TableB` has **ID**, **IsManager**, and **CanChange**.

I'm writing a stored procedure with an input parameter `login`. It needs ultimately return all columns in `TableB` where `login = ID` but it first needs to check `TableA` to see if it needs to use **NewLogin**.

So, can someone help me write a query that says "show me all columns in `TableB` where ID = (login OR NewLogin)"?

Thanks!

EDIT: Added code:

```
DECLARE @login varchar(30) = 'test'

SELECT ISNULL(NewLogin, @login) AS NewLogin, TableB .IsManager, TableB.CanChange
FROM TableA
LEFT JOIN TableB ON TableB.ID = ISNULL(NewLogin, @login)
WHERE OldLogin = @login
```

THe above code works only if @login exists in TableA. I get no results if it doesn't exist in that table.

Comment: We could write you a query, or, you could try it yourself and post a question asking for advice on how to make it work.

Comment: I *have* tried it myself, and this *was* my post asking for advice. I just didn't post my specific code. I'll do that now.

Answer (score 0):

if I'm understanding that correctly...

```
SELECT TableB.*
FROM TableB
LEFT JOIN TableA ON TableB.id IN (TableA.OldLogin, TableB.NewLogin)
```

?

Comment: But this doesn't take into account the input parameter @login. I substituted "TableB.id" for my input parameter, but that didn't work.

Comment: No, but I had mentioned there was an input parameter. If the purpose of my query is still unclear, please let me know so I can try to explain it better. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use IFNULL(a,b) to return b if a is null.

EDIT: I assumed mysql, not sure if that works in other languages. You could also use COALESCE, it takes any number of args and returns the first non-null argument.

```
DECLARE @login varchar(30) = 'test'

SELECT IFNULL(TableA.NewLogin, @login) AS NewLogin, TableB.IsManager, TableB.CanChange
FROM TableA
LEFT JOIN TableB ON 
  TableB.ID = IFNULL(TableA.NewLogin, @login)
WHERE OldLogin = @login
```

Comment: I'm using ISNULL...same thing, no?

Comment: What kind of SQL? Based on what you are saying I think you are not using mysql, maybe SQL Server?

Comment: I've re-tagged, adding "SQL Server".

Comment: ISNULL in SQL Server acts like IFNULL in mysql. I'm assuming that the OldLogin is always in TableA. If it is not, then your WHERE clause would eliminate all results.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @login varchar(30) = 'test'
SELECT DISTINCT TableB.*
FROM TableA
  INNER JOIN TableB ON TableB.ID = NewLogin OR TableB.ID = @login
```